# Lotus Notes 8.5.1: Undo Declining a Meeting?

Tags: lotus-notes

In Lotus Notes 8.5.1, I ended up declining a meeting due to a earlier, conflicting meeting. About an hour after I declined the second meeting, the first one was rescheduled. So, now I want to un-decline the second one. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I don't think there is a way. Perhaps ask the meeting organiser to remove you from the schedule, and add you again?  Or just manually book the time on your side, and use a post-it on your monitor to remind you of the meeting :p

Comment: It seems like removing and re-adding on the meeting creator's part is, indeed, the only way. Thanks.

Comment: Just another hint: when declining a meeting there is a Dialog. In this dialog there is a checkbox saying something like "keep me informed"... If you check this when declining, then you will be invited again, if something in the meeting changes... Unfortunately this option is not available AFTER declining, so that removing / readding is the only way, if you forgot to tick the option.

Answer (score 15):

IBM have a [tips document](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/notestipsblog.nsf/dx/find-a-meeting-you-have-declined-or-delegated) that describe how to do this.

From the calendar Views panel, under `Lists` select `Entries and Notices`. Then you should be able to find the declined meeting request. Sort by an appropriate column to find the request (`Last Modified` worked for me since it was a recent request).

Once you've found the declined request you can open it and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the declined meeting from the 'all calendar entries' view, you can choose to accept it, cancelling the decline.

Answer (score -2):

With Lotus Notes 7 you can go to the calendar view and select "All Calendar Entries" tab in the main window.  This will show the declined events.

Links
http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/03399144bc53ba548525704a004dab74?OpenDocument

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/f30aced44ae72eda8525704a004d8ea1?OpenDocument

Comment: Can you summarize what's in those links so your answer is still useful if they go dead? Please read the help article on answering for information on [giving links context](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).